# What's the potential best model to solve this classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I'm facing a classification problem as follows:

the features: an array of floats. The relationship between features and target is not notable, so I'm not expecting a 90% accuracy or so. As long as it can solve the problem it is good for me.

the target: a float that could be positive or negative or zero.

the problem: predict the `sign` of the target (i.e. `0`, `+`, or `-`) so that the sum of `sign * target` reaches maximum.

As comparison, I can predict with a brutal force guess using only one feature, for example, if feature>0, then predict `+`, otherwise `-`.

Currently I'm using a random forest with a metric `f1_weighted` and 5 fold CV, this does not give good test result compared with brutal force guess. While the training and CV results are close to theoretical maximum sum.

What could be the best approach to modify my current model/create a new model if necessary to get the test set result at least better than brutal force guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you didn't say anything about how many objects or features you are working with -- which can be helpful for the optimal classifier choice.  Furthermore, a lot of analysts implement complex models before knowing how to perform microsurgery so that a meaningful description of class separation can be made.

It's always best to start by using straightforward multivariate linear regression first when the targets are -1, +1, such that you regress all the +/- variates on to the predictors.   Reason is, because you first need to know if the class separation between +/- is **linearly separable**.

If RF is breaking down, try LREG (multivariate linreg), followed by k-nearest neighbors, discriminant analysis, learning vector quantization, and then support vector machines with RBF kernel, and then neural networks.

With regard to the 5-fold CV, since you didn't provide your total sample size, you should evaluate 2-, 5-, 10-fold, and LOOCV CV approaches.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to abandon this question because I cannot provide more info than this.